# Visual Studio 2022 Go to definition System.Int32 operators missing

Tags: c#, integer, visual-studio-2022

Try to right click on a int declaration and choose Go to definition. You will see the def of int, but the operators are missing?

How can you make them show up.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: What do u expect to see for the definition on In32? and what operators are missing?

Answer (score 0):

These operators are only shown when they are overloaded. E.g. for `System.String` the definition shows the `==`, `!=` and `implicit` (.Net Core only) operators.

The arithmetic operators for `System.Int32` seem to be implemented by the compiler and are not overloaded (i.e., they are not implemented as static methods) for efficiency reasons.